# Add button in a table retrieved from database with php

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am able to get all the content of my table from the database using php.
How can I add a button in one of the column of the table , or either another component like a select or a checkbox....

I post a pic to make it more clear.
[image]
I get the table using php but how to insert the component in the row?

```
$db = new mysqli("...", "...", "...", "...");

    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * from ...";
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    echo "
<table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>";
    /* Get field information for all columns */
    while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
        echo "
        <th>" . $finfo->name . "</th>";
    }
    echo "
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   echo "<tr class='info'>
    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['device'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['paymenttype'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
                <td> add </td>
                                   </tr>"; 
    } 
    echo "
    </tbody>
</table>";
    ?>
```

-----------------update

```
            echo "<tr class='info'>
            <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['device'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['paymenttype'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>

            <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
            <td><a href='http://yourlink' >delete</a></td>


                           </tr>";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>";
    /* Get field information for all columns */
    while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
        echo "
        <th>" . $finfo->name . "</th>";
    }
    echo "
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   echo "<tr class='info'>
    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['device'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['paymenttype'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
                <td> <button class='btn' >Button</button> </td>
 </tr>"; 
        } 
        echo "
        </tbody>
    </table>";
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, i am gonna try your code as well. I did find solution as well with (posted my own solution)

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution

```
<td><a class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'  href='send.php?name=".$row['name']."'>Send</a></td>
```